# What is the impact of having empty (nulls) in the fact table's join (to dimension table) column?

Tags: powerbi

If there is a missing dimension record for a given fact key (joining column), then on the visual this is represented by (blank). For example - say there is a product id in fact table which is missing in the Product dim table.

What happens instead if the fact table has null value on the joining column? For example - say the sales fact joins product dim on product id. What happens if the product id in the fact table is null?

Comment: For the provided sample you will have some difficulties with measures. For example 
 `SUMX(product,CALCULATE(SUM(Fact[qty]))`<`SUM(Fact[qty])`

Comment: These rows will be ignored. It's good practice to fill nulls in fact and dimension with some default number, called undefined for example.